# Apple AirPlay mirroring SDK

Tags: ios, airplay

Is there an SDK for Airplay Mirroring? I'm working on a prototype for a device that should mirror the screen of an iOS device. I understand this may be achievable by paying royalties to Apple for each device, and I'm fine with that. But how would I go about prototyping this features? There is a lot of info on writing iOS apps that support AirPlay, but I can't find much info about the hardware side.

**Update**
Based on the exchanges in the comments, I wondering now whether this is at all possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to be an AirPlay **destination**?

Comment: @TomHarrington Yes, I'm trying to build a device that will do the function of an Apple TV, for instance.

Comment: Where have you seen that "this may be achievable by paying royalties to Apple for each device"?

Comment: Well, I know for a fact that there are audio equipments that are AirPlay-enabled such AV/receivers. I don't recall my sources, but I had heard at some point that they were charging a small amount for each such device. And knowing Apple, they would either charge royalties, or not allow it at all. The question, I guess, is whether this is at all possible?

Comment: Audio over airplay is rather different to mirroring, what those devices are doing is having an audio feed streamed to them, whereas it sounds like what you want to do is have your own hardware box that acts as a fully functional airplay video receiver?

Comment: These guys seemed to have figured it out: http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

Comment: It seems like these guys have an answer: http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/airtame-wireless-hdmi-for-everyone--2?c=activity It doesn't seem like Apple allows this in any way

Comment: I've been trying to do something similar here and have been looking at comparable software, i.e.: AirServer (OSX/Windows)
Reflector (OSX/Windows)
AirReceiver (Android)
X-Mirage (OSX/Windows)
AirPin PRO (Android)
EZCast Screen (Android)
Xiaomi Milian (Android/runs on Xiaomi Box)

Comment: @yydl apply doesn't provide licenses for "software"/applications. Only for hardware devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is not possible to have a device that can mirror the iOS screen via AirPlay mirroring. While I couldn't find an official statement to this effect, these guys seem to have done the work for their project:

http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/airtame-wireless-hdmi-for-everyone--2?c=activity

Hopefully things may change in the future, and I'll be sure to update the answer if they do.

Comment: I believe these guys are using their own protocol for it.